# Xcode project crashing every time it is opened

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode10

Every time I open my project in Xcode ( `Version 10.0 beta (10L176w)` ) I get a crash.

[image: Crash log from Xcode after attempting to open the project]

**What have I TRIED to do to fix the problem?**

- I have tried using `Xcode 9` but that didn't seem to work either.
- I have tried clicking another file as soon as I open the
  project, but that does not seem to work.
- I have tried going to the directory in the error log, but it would not take me there.
- I have tried right-clicking on `xxx.xcodeproj` and then clicking `Show Packaged Contents` then deleting the `xcuserdata` folder (also tried with `xxx.xcworkspace`).

**Expected result:**

For my project not to crash every time it is opened.

**Actual result:**

A crash every time I open my project.

**What caused it?**

I can't know for sure what caused it, but it happened when I was adding Binaries and Libraries I created (I am new to it, so may have done something wrong). You can also see a few lines in the log screenshot about Frameworks, so this might have been the cause.

**Why does it matter?**

I am unable to work on my project, halting progress, as neither the `.xcodeproj` or the `.xcworkspace` will open. I am hesitant (and also it's bit of a pain) to edit the files to write my code. I wouldn't like to start ALL over again.

**I am not looking to remake my project, and that is a last resort.**

---

Is there some sort of project/cache cleaning I can do without opening the project (something similar to **`⌘ + ⇧ + K`**)?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask me. If you require a certain part of the crash log, let me know.**

Comment: @matt This project is entirely made in Xcode 10, and it crashed whilst adding a framework. It still crashes in Xcode 9.

Comment: OK, good info! Well then I think the answer is quite simple. The project is hosed. Make a new project and migrate your code and other files into it (but _not_ the framework).

Comment: @matt I was looking for a cleaner solution than that, that will be last resort :/

Comment: @matt I just feel like there is some folder which is outdated when updating frameworks or something, causing a conflict and a crash.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I thought you wanted to move forward with this.

Comment: @matt I think I may have to, which is a pain

Comment: It's not a pain. This kind of thing happens all the time. Migrate and move on. By the way, your hesitation suggests you are not under git version control. That's a mistake right there...

Comment: @matt Ok, it was actually much easier and quicker than I thought. I am not using git version control, but I will look into it in the future. Currently I do not want to be spending the £7/month

Comment: Git costs nothing to use. I think you're very silly not to use it. It's built right in. Xcode begs you to turn on git support when you create a project. Just say yes.

Comment: @matt I thought it was a paid service? 

Comment: You seem to have thought a lot of things that turn out not to be true. This is a lucky day for you!

Comment: @matt Haha  I will look now I guess

Comment: @matt It does say you have to pay for a private repository https://imgur.com/a/lNYCQKJ

Comment: git is not the same thing as github. Also bitbucket private repositories are free if you want offsite storage, but I was not saying you need offsite storage. I'm just saying you need version control. Do something you regret and poof, you've got a time machine.

Comment: @matt The learning overload of realising git is not github...

Comment: Is there a "my head just exploded" emoji? :)

Comment: You guessed it... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just re-made the project. I started using **git** for the first time as well, so I will stay with that from now on, as it will reduce the chances of this happening again :)